# IIS: Getting a 500 Server Error when trying to configure IIS on machine to work with include files

Tags: asp.net, iis, include

In my wwwroot home folder I have an index.html file. inside of that I have references to include files such as:

```
<!--#include file="include/globalSearch_index.inc"-->
<!--#include file="include/footer_index.inc"-->
```

In the same folder I also have a folder called "include" which contains these files. The *.inc files just contain snippets of reusable html

By default if I try to view this using localhost/index.html these instructions are ignored and the content on the index.html page alone get rendered. I followed the instructions in this [page](http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7) to set up the appropriate handler mapping in IIS.

[image]

Now however, I get the following error page. [image]I have reset IIS and also restarted the computer (I'm trying to do this on my local machine by the way not a separate server). As per the instructions on that error page I have checked to see that I have .Net Extensibility Feature installed (I have). I do not however have a web.config file in my wwwroot folder. If I do require one of those then what needs to be in it?

Is there anything else that I need to try?

Comment: general rule with a 500: Go look at the server error log. there's no point in randomly flailing around until you KNOW what the problem is.

Comment: @MarcB This isn't on a server, it's on my local machine. I checked the Event Viewer but there wasn't anything in there for those times

Comment: iis logs errors to a file.should be in inetpub somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling about it for another length of time I finally got it running. For anyone who should happen to navigate here after having a similar issue: So there seemed to be a final step missing when creating that Module Mapping in IIS. After filling in the required fields on the popup before clicking "OK" click on the "Request Restrictions" button. On this second popup check the "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to" checkbox and then hit OK on both popups and that should resolve it.

This creates a web.config in the folder in which you created the mapping that looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="SSI-html" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="File" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```